# How I can call setstate from another file?

Tags: flutter, state

I have class :

```
class FavoritesState extends State<Favorites> {
  var configOk = isConfigLoaded;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (configOk) {
      return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: stationList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, position) {
            return StationCard(stationList[position]);
          },
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return LoadingScreen();
    }
  }

  void callback() {
    setState(() {
      this.configOk = true;
    });
  }
}
```

And I have method:

```
Future<http.Response> getConfig() async {
    //Load Config 
    isConfigLoaded = true;
}
```

I need at the end this method call setstate in FavoritesState and upload information there. How I can do this? Thank you.

Comment: it would be probably be easier to pass a callback to the `getConfig()` function

Comment: Can you tell me how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use a `FutureBuilder` if you're only updating the state of the widget once. The FutureBuilder will force your widget to rebuild as soon as your `getConfig()` call has completed.
This would simplify things:

```
class Favorites extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: getConfig(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.data == null) {
          // display the loading screen as long as your getConfig() call hasn't finished
          return LoadingScreen();
        }
        return Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: stationList.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, position) {
              return StationCard(stationList[position]);
            },
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

And then tweak your call to something like this:

```
Future<http.Response> getConfig() async {
  //Load Config

  // return your result
  return result;
}
```